# Orbital angular momentum eigenstates in the $|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space, spherical-harmonics

Consider the orbital angular momentum operators $L^2$ and $L_z$. In the $|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ representation using spherical coordinates those operators actions are given by

$$L^2\varphi(\mathbf{r})=-\hbar^2\left(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}+\dfrac{1}{\tan \theta} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}\right)\varphi(\mathbf{r})$$

$$L_z\varphi(\mathbf{r})=-i\hbar \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\varphi(\mathbf{r}).$$

Now, we know that $[L^2,L_z]=0$ so that it is possible to construct a basis of state space of simultaneous eigenstates of both $L^2 $ and $L_z$. We also know that the eigenvalues of $L^2$ are of the form $l(l+1)\hbar^2$ with $l$ integral or half-integral. On the other hand the eigenvalues of $L_z$ are of the form $m\hbar$ and with fixed $l$ we have that $m$ can only take on the values $-l,-l+1,\dots,l-1,l$. The simultaneous eigenvalue equations are then

$$L^2\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=l(l+1)\hbar^2\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$$

$$L_z\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=m\hbar \psi(r,\theta,\phi)$$

Now, the book I'm studying (Cohen's Quantum Mechanics book) states the following:

> In the eigenvalue equations, $r$ does not appear in any differential operator, so we can consider it to be a parameter and *take into account only the $\theta$- and $\phi$-dependence of $\psi$. Thus, we denote by $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ a common eigenfunction of $L^2$ and $L_z$ which corresponds to the eigenvalues $l(l+1)\hbar^2$ and $m\hbar$.
>
> $$L^2Y^m_l(\theta,\phi) = l(l+1)\hbar^2Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$$
>
> $$L_zY^m_l(\theta,\phi)=m\hbar Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$$
>
> That equations give the $\theta$- and $\phi$-dependence of the eigenfunctions of $L^2$ and $L_z$. Once the solutions $Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$ of these equations has been found, these eigenfunctions will be obtained in the form:
>
> $$\psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi)=f(r)Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$$
>
> where $f(r)$ is a function of $r$ which appears as na integration constant for the partial differential equation.

Now, I don't see how the author concludes that *given $l$ and $m$ the eigenfunction $\psi_{l,m}$ is of the form $\psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi) = f(r)Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$*. This conclusion to come out from thin air. By the way things are written it seems that $Y^m_l$ is *by definition* the eigenfunction corresponding to $l$ and $m$. But then the author states that the eigenfunction is really $\psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi)=f(r)Y^l_m(\theta,\phi)$.

Indeed the equations defining the eigenfunctions of $L^2$ and $L_z$ are differential equations. Viewing from this point, $\psi_{l,m}$ is the form of a separable solution. But there are the ones which are not separable.

In general, considering the way the author presented things, *how does he conclude the general form of eigenfunctions* and what is his point on calling $Y^m_l$ the angular dependence of the eigenfunctions

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is unclear to you here. You *know* the spectrum fo $L_z$ and $L^2$. The $\psi_{l,m}$ are eigenfunctions for each possible eigenvalue. So why do you claim that there could be non-separable eigenfunctions? Writing a general non-separable function as $\sum_i f_i(r) Y^{l_i}_{m_i}(\theta,\phi)$, you should be able to see that only the separable ones are eigenfunctions.

Comment: The author is talking first and foremost of the eigenfunction of $\nabla^2$ in spherical coordinates which involves all 3 coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$. This eigenfunction he is denoting as $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$. Next, he is using the explicit form of $\nabla^2$ in spherical coordinates and showing that it can be broken up into a piece that's purely $r$ dependent and a piece that's purely $(\theta,\phi)$ dependent. The latter turns out to be simply $L^2$. He concludes that the full eigenfunction $\psi$ can be constructed out of eigenfunctions of $L^2$, namely $Y^m_l$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\psi_{l,m}$ satisfies, for each $l$ and $m$, the equations

$$L^2\psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi)=l(l+1)\hbar^2\psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi),$$

$$L_z\psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi)=m\hbar \psi_{l,m}(r,\theta,\phi).$$

But we also know that, *by definition*, $Y_{l, m}(\theta, \phi)$ satisfy *the same* equations.

Then, unless the eigenvalue equations for $Y_{l,m}$ are degenerate, which can proved to be not by solving the differential equations, we must conclude that $\psi_{l,m}$ and $Y_{l,m}$ are the same, apart from a "constant" factor which does not depend on $\theta$ or $\phi$, but *does* depend on $r$.
The author then simply proceeds in calling this still unknown factor $f(r)$.